# Python and Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Hi I'm trying to parse html from this [website](http://www.ukpets.co.uk/ukp/?sf=1716769780&rtn=temp87_224_76_126_at_1456&display_profile=&section=Commercial&sub=Search_&rws=&method=search&tb=comdir1_8&class=comdir1_8&search_form=on&rf=coname&st=Food)

However it takes for ever for the soup to load the whole html (about 17 seconds to print to terminal), I do realize this is only because of the website itself (as other directories seem to load instantly), but here is my code just in case:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url1 = 'http://www.ukpets.co.uk/ukp/?sf=1716769780&rtn=temp87_224_76_126_at_1456&display_profile=&section=Commercial&sub=Search_&rws=&method=search&tb=comdir1_8&class=comdir1_8&search_form=on&rf=coname&st=Food'
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url1), 'lxml')
print soup
```

So my question, is there any other parser that could get this job done faster or can i use something along with bs

P.S. also tried selenium

Comment: Try request, http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

Comment: Just an advice: separate the two operation: load the html in a file, and then parse it. Then use timeit to control the time taken by both operation. If the first takes all the time, there is no use trying to optimize the second...

Comment: If the problem is with *loading* the page (doing the HTTP request itself), then the parser is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dunno what the problem is for you but this series of statements executed in the blink of an eye on my old computer. You could try doing this.

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> from urllib.request import urlopen
>>> URL = 'http://www.ukpets.co.uk/ukp/?sf=1716769780&rtn=temp87_224_76_126_at_1456&display_profile=&section=Commercial&sub=Search_&rws=&method=search&tb=comdir1_8&class=comdir1_8&search_form=on&rf=coname&st=Food'
>>> HTML = urlopen ( URL )
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup ( HTML )
C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py:166: UserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system ("lxml"). This usually isn't a problem, but if you run this code on another system, or in a different virtual environment, it may use a different parser and behave differently.

To get rid of this warning, change this:

 BeautifulSoup([your markup])

to this:

 BeautifulSoup([your markup], "lxml")

  markup_type=markup_type))
```